# How do I run a function in jQuery after Bootstrap completes a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I am working on a final project due in less than 24 hours and am working on the final requirement, which is to add custom Javascript to my code that is not complete bootstrap.

I have a bootstrap created form with a submit button. I used jQuery to trigger a bootstrap modal to appear displaying a success message upon the clicking of that button. The modal closes when the user clicks the "x" or clicks outside the modal window.

Once the modal window closes, I am attempting to hide the form from the page using jquery. Here is my code snippet below:

```
//the modal submit button click event
$('#myModal').modal(show);   

//the form dissapears after the modal is closed. #formToggle is the id applid to the <form> 

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#formToggle').on('show', function(){
        $('#formToggle').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen when the modal is closed

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function () {
 $("#formToggle").hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yd9nffxe/6/

Comment: I trid this just now, but the form is still there when i close the modal. maybe i am incorrect to use the id #formToggle on the form element? Should i select its parent <div> instead?

Comment: It shouldn't matter even it's in form or parent div as per my jsfiddle example as long as the ID is unique. Can you post a fiddle link with your snippet(including the form) to check the possible error.

Comment: Please see this I scraped your snippet and it works in this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/yd9nffxe/8/

Comment: I am suspecting it isnt necessary the function i am using, but that something is actually wrong with jquery loading on my project. I have no idea how to fix it. I will post a link to my repo in github to show what i mean

Comment: In index.html, bootstrap and jquery libraries must be loaded before the modal.js. While in modal.js the attribute value of the style should be 'display:none'

Answer (score 0):

use `hidden.bs.modal`:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    // do your stuff here...
});
```

> hidden.bs.modal occurs when the modal is fully hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)